# Why is Java.Time.Year arbitrarily limited to less than its primitive limits?

Tags: java, time, limit

The Java 8 doc page for Java.Time.Year states that the minimum and maximum supported years are -999,999,999 and 999,999,999, respectively.

> #### Field Summary
>
> `static int` `MAX_VALUE`The maximum supported year, '+999,999,999'.
>
> `static int` `MIN_VALUE`The minimum supported year, '-999,999,999'.

However, the primitive type variable that stores the year value is an **int**, which should be capable of storing between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

```
/**
 * The year being represented.
 */
private final int year;
```

Why are there these arbitrary limits?

Comment: Because `java.time` is mostly based on ISO, and ISO year says that it *"must have an **agreed-upon number of extra year digits** beyond the four-digit minimum"*, at least according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Years). That resolves to 9 digits.

Comment: A use of 999_999_999 is non-arbitrary, as it includes every possible year from -999_999_999 to +999_999_999, so every possible year with up to 9 digits is usable. Not every possible year with up to 10 digits is usable when using INT_MAX, only 21% of those years are available.

Comment: @Andreas a four digit minimum resolves not to 9 digits but still to four (-9999 until +9999).

Comment: @MenoHochschild *"extra year digits"* resolves to a max of 9 digits when year is stored in an `int`, since an `int` cannot store full range of 10 digits.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for clarification. Was a misunderstanding on my side (I am not a native English speaker).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason 999,999,999 is used is not linked to any specific issue with parsing implementation within the code.

It is likely to have been selected as it is the maximum value of any number that consists of between 1 and 9 digits. We cannot store a full set of years to 10 digits with an INT, as 9,999,999,999 (and frankly another 79% of possible 10 digit numbers) cannot be stored in an integer. It is important to note that the formatter itself can support individual numbers up to 64 digits seamlessly, and only uses MIN/MAX for error checking. If the Min/Max were raised to INT_MIN and INT_MAX, it would still function without issues. Values exceeding INT_MAX would properly throw an error and prevent any issues regarding integer overflow, so there is no concern regarding any sort of parse failure.

```
    ISO_LOCAL_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4, 10, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendLiteral('-')
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

Year is either 4 numbers for traditional ISO, i.e. 0-9999, or has a +/-, i.e. +999999 for Year 999999.

Of note is that the ISO_LOCAL_DATE Formatter accepts 10-digit years by default, excluding the +/- sign, so a value of +9,876,543,210 is actually properly parsed, but exceeds the acceptable values for MAX_YEAR.

```
Text '+9876543210-10-31' could not be parsed: Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): 9876543210
```

Everything in the [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/6ea3aea950d1/src/share/classes/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java) supports up to 64 digits, parsing a digit at a time. All these values are parsed safely as BigIntegers, and carefully multiplied by 10 as the index moves towards the right, and upon completion are converted and stored in a parse context consisting of field names and longs, even though fields Months and Days can clearly be stored as INTS. These are later converted back into their associated primitives.

Practically speaking, DateTimeFormatterBuilder could definitely use `2,147,483,647` as a valid min/max year without breaking.

Realistically speaking, the description of "Java accepts any year value up to 9 digits" presents a concrete barrier where there is no chance of integer overflow or confusion when of adding two years together, and reduces any potential black box confusion as to why year 2,100,000,000 works but 2,200,000,000 breaks to a halt.